# LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' not working when store mysl result in txt file

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try to store mysql result in txt file lines terminated is not working

```
select * from users INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql- 
files/users.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';---> not working
```

the result are all in one line 
    "1"|"John@test.com"|"20"|"John"|"test"/"2"|"omar@test.com"|"21"|"Omar"|"test2""3"|"Mytest@test.com"|"30"|"Mytest"|"test3"

Comment: You sure that you checked the output file with editor/viewer that understand the unix EOL? For windows tools (like old notepad) you need \r\n instead of just \n.

Comment: \r\n fix the problem thank you